# How to reset the detail formatters in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I think I messed up the detail formatters. I cannot display this page in the settings anymore (it's just white) and I can't hover any varaible anymore in debug (i get "Multiple prolems have occured": "Label Job", "compute variable details").
Where are these settings stored so I can reset them? Are these workspace specific (which settings are workspace specific, which not?)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think these settings are in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.prefs` file (along with other Java Debug settings).

Almost all preferences are workspace specific.

Also look in the workspace `.metadata/.log` file for more detailed errors.

Comment: @greg-44 thanks a lot. I had the same problem and solved it with the help of your answer.